# Difference between onEvent.Listen() and addEventListener

Tags: dart-html

I'm relatively new to Dart. I'm mainly building very small Dart/HTML applications on Dartpad, but I would like to know:

what are the main differences between `element.addEventListener(type, callback);` and `element.onEvent.listen(callback);`, and where will those differences provide me an advantage, in what way, and in what situations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like no one is going to give an answer, so I'll share a bit of my knowledge for anyone else who may have spotted this.

- [element.onEvent](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-html/Element/onClick.html) is a [Stream](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-async/Stream-class.html), where the [listen](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) method subscribes to that Stream. It seems it can add multiple event listeners.
- [element.addEventListener](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-html/EventTarget/addEventListener.html) seems to be a plain event listener. It can also add multiple events.

The only differences I can see are that addEventListener can add a listener dynamically to different types of events as you can pass a string into it -

```
var str = "click";
element.addEventListener(str, (_) {
    print(1);
});
```

and possibly Streams may have unique methods that allow you to customize your event listener with element.onEvent.listen more.